# Can we call API function from another API function?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetData(string requestString)
    {
        DetailsReq req = new DetailsReq();

        // Some logic to extract parameters from request string

        IActionResult res = await GetDetails(req);
        return Ok(res);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails([FromBody] DetailsReq req)
    { 
         DetailsRes res = new DetailsRes();
         return Ok(res);
    }
```

Requirement is to add new function GetData() to Dot Net core API. There is a existing POST method GetDetails() which gives the similar response.

I have two options.

1. Copy logic from GetDetails() and use in GetData().
2. Call GetDetails() in GetData()

My question is can we call API method from another method? Is it good practice?

Comment: You should probably separate the logic to another method in a service class so that both API actions can call that one.

Comment: Yep, you should separe the logic of GetDetails() to another class, and use the new class in the controller.

Comment: Take a look at this https://dev.to/scorpio69/how-to-web-api-net-core-basics-to-advanced-part-4-service-layer-31gk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we call API method from another method?

To answer this, yes you can call one `Method/Function` from another `Method/Function` within the same `Controller Class`. you could see following example:

**Method: GetDataFromAnotherAPI**

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> GetDataFromAnotherAPI()
        {
            
                var response = new MultipleDBQueryExecutionModel();
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                var data = "";
                var baseUrl = "https://localhost:44361/UserLog/";
                var methodName = "GetData";

                handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                var client = new HttpClient(handler);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

                var responseFromApi = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl + methodName);
                if (responseFromApi.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    data = await responseFromApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                }

                return Ok(data);
          
            


        }
```

**Note:** `HttpClientHandler` is not related to your issue. I have used that to handle `https certificate` issue.

**Method: GetData: Which I am calling within the Same Controller Class**

```
 public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            var data = _context.multipleDBQueryExecutionModels.ToList();
            return Ok(data);
        }
```

**Controller Class:**

```
public class UserLogController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public UserLogController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Above two method belongs to `UserLogController`  controller class. and I am calling `GetData` method within `GetDataFromAnotherAPI` method.

**Output:**

[image]

> Is it good practice?

Now let's discuss your point `"Copy logic from GetDetails() and use in GetData()."`. No this doesn't considered as `good practice` on `Object Oriented Programming` as it doesn't encourage to write redundant code.

Here [`SOLID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp) principle comes to rescue. Which tell make your `repository/business` logic in a seperate `class/Interface` as per [`SOLID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp) its called [`Interface Segregation Principle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp#the-interface-segregation-principle). You could have look on [`SOLID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp), your time would be worth using.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Will mark it as answer. I have one doubt, can we call the function directly like GetData(); in GetDataFromAnotherAPI(); without including baseurl part. Is there any disadvantage of that?

Comment: If there are within the same controller then you can. Regarding the disadvantage, not really however, this not a best practice as it breaks the `SOLID` principle.